# Could not load file or assembly 'PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, dotfuscator

I started getting this error while compiling my project which is targeted to WP8:

> Error 47  The "PreEmptive.Tasks.Dotfuscate" task could not be loaded
>   from the assembly C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\PreEmptive\Dotfuscator\4\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Tasks.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\PreEmptive\Dotfuscator\4\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Tasks.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask

I checked that MSBuild folder does not have "PreEmptive" folder. But I have been building this project without any issues so far. I am not sure what got changed which resulted into this error.